# How to drop duplicate columns based on another schema in spark scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine I have two different dataframes with similar schemas:

```
df0.printSchema
root
 |-- single: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- double: integer (nullable = false)
```

and:

```
df1.printSchema
root
 |-- newColumn: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- single: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- double: double (nullable = false)
```

Now I merge these two schemas like below and create a new dataframe with this merged schema:

```
val consolidatedSchema = df0.schema.++:(df1.schema).toSet

val uniqueConsolidatedSchemas = StructType(consolidatedSchema.toSeq)

val emptyDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], uniqueConsolidatedSchemas)

emptyDF.printSchema
root
 |-- newColumn: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- single: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- double: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- double: double (nullable = false)
```

But as you can see, I have two fields with name of `double`, but with different data types.
**How can I keep the one that its data type is matched with the one in `df0` schema and drop the other one?**

I want the final schema to be like this:

```
finalDF.printSchema
root
 |-- newColumn: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- single: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- double: integer (nullable = false)
```

I really appreciate if you suggest any other method to merge these two schemas and reach my goal.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the second schema to exclude the fields that are already present in the first one before you concatenate the lists:

```scala
val uniqueConsolidatedSchemas = StructType(
  df0.schema ++ df1.schema.filter(c1 =>
    !df0.schema.exists(c0 => c0.name == c1.name)
  )
)
```